# Как между собою связаны структура репозиториев, сервисов и методов rest

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, rest

Не очень могу понять, как у нас связываются сервисы, репозитории, которые через хранимые процедуры получают данные из БД. и REST контроллер обрабатывающий запросы клиента.

Если есть пример их взаимной работы можете привести пожалуйста.

Comment: А где это - у вас?

Comment: связывается DI,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У спринга для этого есть `JdbcCall`

[DATA Access with JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

[Пример](https://logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/spring-call-stored-procedure.html)